# SharePoint 2010 Application Pages, Safe Mode

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964680(office.12).aspx pages that are compiled should allow inline code.

I have this in a grid column on a application page:

```
Text='Open <%# Eval("Title") %>'
```

It is not being evaluated like it is still in safe mode. Code behind for the page works fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `<%...%>` expression evaluation syntax is not allowed for server controls. It has actually nothing to do with SharePoint. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h.aspx) about the details of ASP.NET markup.